# npm Json parsing error for @angular/cli installation

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm trying to install angular 6 with: 
**$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest**
Using
**node -v**  -  v8.11.1 
**npm -v**  -  6.0.1

**OS** - Linux (Mint 18)

Getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...um":"7e1bd7294bd522da'
```

**Note:** Have already tried **npm cache verify** and **npm cache clean --force**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a problem with your node/npm and not with Angular CLI.

Just completely uninstall the Node.js from Programs and Features and Re-install it,Make sure that you completely deleted all the node-modules and npm caches in the Npm folder and not present anywhere else

Comment: Tried uninstalling node and installing it again still getting the same result, Also tried nvm and tried the same with 8.11.2 and 9.2.0 but getting the same result, is it because of some remaining file (even if I'm using nvm to specify the version of node to be used)?

Comment: can you try eleting the package-lock.json and after this run npm install.

Comment: I'm using nvm now with node 8.11.2 and npm 5.5.1, after deleting the package-lock.json.5 from the **version/v8.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/** I'm getting the same result

Comment: that is very strange, somewhere your files still exists

Comment: Removing nodejs completely and installing it again worked thank you!